# Solving the "PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" error in VS 2013 WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, bitmap

I'm developing a universal c# application for Windows, and Windows Phone 8, and this is my first application in this environment.

I had a problem concerning the use of Bitmap class. when I try to compile the app, it doesn't recognize it, so I searched for the problem and I found out that I had to downloaded a "system.drawing.dll" file in order to include it in references. The problem has been solved. But now when I compile the app it gives me another error:

> La classe de base ou l'interface 'System.MarshalByRefObject' dans l'assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' référencé par le type 'System.Drawing.Image' n'a pas pu être résolue

and now I don't know how can I solve this problem.

Comment: You're trying to use desktop code on a phone. You *never* **ever** have to "download" core CLR libraries.  Either their version of the framework is installed or it is not.  So, everything you have done so far, undo it.  It's all junk.  Once you get back to a stable working version of your application, ask how to accomplish whatever goal you were trying to accomplish when you started going down this road.  *That's the question you should be asking*.

Comment: Hello Will! Yes that's what I realised, I was trying to work with Bitmap class which is unsupported by windows phone 8. Now I m working with WriteableBitmap class, and everything goes well till now. Anyway thank you for responding me! :)

Comment: Glad to hear you already solved your real issue. Watch out for parts of the framework that don't belong on the phone!